# htaccess redirect not changing the url in address bar

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the following code in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^shop/[A-Z]{3,9}\ /products\.php\?levelID=([^&]+)&level=([^&]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^shop/products\.php$ http://foo.info/product/%1/%2.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /shop/products.php?levelID=$1&level=$2 [L]
```

this successfully rewrites the the dynamic URL internally to

```
http://foo.info/product/9/Laser%20printers.html
```

but I want the link to change automatically in the BROWSER address bar to

```
http://foo.info/product/9/Laser%20printers.html
```

I guess rewrite condition should take care of it but not getting the correct one. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /shop/products\.php\?levelID=([^&]+)&level=([^&]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^shop/products\.php$ http://foo.info/product/%1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /shop/products.php?levelID=$1&level=$2 [L]
```

The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is the first line of the HTTP request, which looks something like:

```
GET /shop/products.php?levelID=123 HTTP/1.1
```

When you added a `/shop` to the very front of that, it made it so that condition will never be met.

Comment: Hi this almost works, however getting the link like following :  .info/product/9/Laser%2520printers.html?levelID=9&level=Laser printers   

can you see ?levelID and level coming at the last?

Comment: @user3899465, yeah, you need a `?` at the end of the redirect, see the edit

Comment: Im getting foo.info/product/9/Laser%2520printers.html?levelID=9&level=Laser printers

I dont want the ?levelID=9&level=Laser printers  after the .html it just need to be foo.info/product/9/Laser%2520printers.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the URL matching following condition

```
product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html
```

to

```
http://inchotepro.info/shop/products.php?levelID=9&level=Laser%20printers
```

then you have to replace

```
[L]
```

with

```
[R=301,L]
```

I hope I got u right.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question properly.. please check now and let me know.. as I want the clean URL to be there on the address bar.. tried that [R=301, L] previously but the link doesnt seem to change.

Comment: Let me tell you what I understood..you want to type http://foo.info/product/9/Laser%20printers.html in the URL and want to display this content through /shop/products.php?levelID=$1&level=$2  internally? Is that so? otherwise give example using URLs